# How to Save/Load singleton class

Tags: c#, compact-framework, singleton

I have configuration entity in my .NET CF application and I want to use singleton for this. Configuration can be changed and has to be saved/restored for next time application launch. I want to use xml serialize/deserialize, it also provides a possibility to change configuration over xml file.
The question is how to save and restore singleton? Deserialization creates a new instance of singleton class, but it means that it will be two instances of the singleton class at the moment.

I have found a solution with ISerializable interface, but it seems that it does not work with compact framework
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Is there any way to obtain the same behavior with .NET CF?

Comment: Why would there be two instances? When your app loads, it could immediately deserialize the singleton class, and that would be your only instance. No?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your singleton most likely uses a private constructor in its pattern.  So you'd do something like this:

```
public class MySingleton
{
    private static MySingleton m_instance;

    private MySingleton() { }

    public static MySingleton Instance 
    { 
        get 
        {
             if(m_instance == null)
             {
                 // hydrate m_instance from serialized version
             } 
             return m_instance; 
        }
    }
}
```

or this:

```
public class MySingleton
{
    private static MySingleton m_instance;

    private MySingleton() 
    {
        // load data from config file 
    }

    public static MySingleton Instance 
    { 
        get 
        {
             if(m_instance == null)
             {
                 m_instance = new MySingleton();
             } 
             return m_instance; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I understand Singleton pattern, but the config might be changed outside the compact framework app, from host PC for example. In this case I have to deserialize xml file to a new singleton instance and replace an existing to the new one. As I understand ISerializable interface from MS example allows to deserialize xml to existing singleton instance instead of creation the new instance. So I want something like this in .NET CF. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Are you wanting to replace the existing singleton instance with another at run time?  If so, replace the `m_instance` instance (with a lock around it).  The serialization/deserialization methodology has nothing to do with it being a singleton or not. If you want to know how to serialize deserialize something that is compatible on the desktop and CF, then that's a whole different question.

Comment: Yes, I want to replace existing instance at run time. And my question is replacing m_instance a good solution of my task or it breaks singleton pattern?

Comment: Yes, lock on a sync root and replace it.  You're still returning one and only one instance, so it's still a singleton.